# React SQL Insert Issues

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to do basic signup connection express/axios with phpmyadmin database (mysql).
I've created the front end and linking it to the server. Everything seems to work but for some reason my data is not getting post (inserted) to the table.

Console.log showing data going is as null.
I've been scratching over this for 2 days still don't seem to see where i've made the mistake or why it's not connecting correct.

Any support will be appreciated in trying to fix the issue:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "signup"
});

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    const values = [req.body.name, req.body.email, req.body.password];
    // Using a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection
    const sql = "INSERT INTO `login`(`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    
    
    db.query(sql, values, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
        }
        
        console.log(data);
        return res.json({ success: true, data: data });
    });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 8081');
});
```

The error on console:
[image]

```
function Signup(){

    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name:'',
        email:'',
        password:''
    })

    const Navigate = useNavigate();
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})

    const handleInput = (e) =>{
        setValues(prev => ({...prev, [e.target.name]: [e.target.values]}))
        
    }
    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const err = Validation(values);
        setErrors(err);
        if(err.name==="" && err.email==="" && err.password===""){
            axios.post('http://localhost:8081/signup', values)
            .then(res => console.log(res))
                
            //     {
            //     Navigate('/');
            // })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        }
    }

    return(
        <div className='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-primary vh-100'>
            <div className='bg-white p-3 rounded w-25'>

<form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <h2> Sign Up</h2>
    <div className='mb-3'>
        <label htmlFor='name'><strong>Name</strong></label>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Enter Name' 
        onChange={handleInput} className='form-control rounded-0' name='name'/>
         {errors.name && <span className='text-danger'> {errors.name}</span>}
    </div>
    <div className='mb-3'>
        <label htmlFor='email'><strong>Email</strong></label>
        <input type='email' placeholder='Enter Email' 
        onChange={handleInput} className='form-control rounded-0' name='email'/>
         {errors.email && <span className='text-danger'> {errors.email}</span>}
    </div>

    <div className='mb-3'>
        <label htmlFor='password'><strong>Password</strong></label>
        <input type='password' placeholder='Enter Password' 
        onChange={handleInput} className='form-control rounded-0' name='password'/>
        {errors.password && <span className='text-danger'> {errors.password}</span>}
    </div>
    {/* <a href='/Home'><button className='btn btn-success w-100'><strong>Log in</strong></button></a> */}
    <p> Agree to our policy</p>

    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-success w-100'><strong>Sign in</strong></button>
    {/* <Link to="/" className='btn btn-success w-100'>
        <button type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
      </Link> */}
      <Link to="/login" className='btn btn-deafult border w-100'>
        <button>Login in</button>
      </Link>

    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `value` attribute of input elements and hence `e.target.value` is null, update all the input elements as follows:

```
<input 
        type='text' 
        placeholder='Enter Name' 
        onChange={handleInput} 
        className='form-control rounded-0' 
        name='name' 
        value={values.name}
/>
```

Also its `e.target.value` and not `e.target.values`

Comment: Thank you....stupid errors. Works perfectly now